# wix property value as filesearch name

Tags: wix, burn

I want to specify property's value passed from burn as name of the searching file. But it seems that this is not supported in wix. Any ideas to overcome this? Thanks in advance.

```
<Property Id="OUTPUT_NAME" Secure="yes" />

<Property Id="UNINSTALL_PATH">
  <DirectorySearch Id="UninstallDirSearch" Path="[CommonAppDataFolder]Package Cache" Depth="1">
    <FileSearch Name="[OUTPUT_NAME]" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

Comment: How are you passing it from burn?

Comment: @IlirB, as it mentioned in wix burn documentation
`<MsiPackage>
<MsiProperty Name="OUTPUT_NAME" Value="$(var.TargetFileName)" />
</MsiPackage>`
But that's not the cause.
The problem is that _Filesearch_'s _name_ attribute can't take _property_'s _value_, and I have no idea how to pass data from burn to msi other way :(

Comment: ah right, tricky one.